# How does objc_setAssociatedObject work?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime, objective-c-category

As we know, we can add a variable in Objective-C using a category and runtime methods like 
`objc_setAssociatedObject` and `objc_getAssociatedObject`. For example:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
@interface Person (EmailAddress)
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, copy) NSString *emailAddress;
@end

@implementation Person (EmailAddress)

static char emailAddressKey;

- (NSString *)emailAddress {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, 
                                    &emailAddressKey);
}

- (void)setEmailAddress:(NSString *)emailAddress {
   objc_setAssociatedObject(self, 
                            &emailAddressKey,
                            emailAddress,
                            OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY);
}
@end
```

But does anybody know what does `objc_getAssociatedObject` or `objc_setAssociatedObject` do?
I mean, where are the variable we add to the object(here is `self`) stored? And the relationship between variable and `self`?

Comment: Any reason for not just using the property? I would try to not mess with the runtime without understanding how it works.

Comment: [Here is](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/objc-runtime.mm) their implementation.

Comment: @H2CO3, the file with the actually interesting code is objc-references.mm: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/objc-references.mm

Comment: Note that tacking data onto objects using associated objects should generally only be used as a tool of last resort.  Using it as a part of your design pattern is indicative of a bad design.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code for associated objects is in [objc-references.mm](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/objc-references.mm)
in the Objective-C runtime.

If I understand it correctly, there is one global hash map (`static AssociationsHashMap *_map` in `class AssociationsManager`) that maps the address of an object ("disguised" as `uintptr_t`) to an `ObjectAssociationMap`.

`ObjectAssociationMap` stores all associations for one particular object and is created
when

```
void objc_setAssociatedObject(id object, void *key, id value, objc_AssociationPolicy policy)
```

is called the first time for an object.

`ObjectAssociationMap` is a hash map that maps the `key` to `value` and `policy`.

When an object is deallocated, `_object_remove_assocations()` removes all associations
and releases the values if necessary.

Comment: You are right,there is a global hash map owned by runtime, and all associated objects are stored by the map.Thank you very much!